# How to get the name of the variable instead of the number in the variable using the max function in python

Tags: python, database, variables, max, min

I am trying to grab integers from a database, print them out in there rows, and at the end of printing them out tell me what integer is the greatest and least.  I am using the max and min functions and instead of doing what i want it to do it is printing out the largest and least number of all the variables instead of printing out the variable itself.

Code:

```
import pyodbc


one = 0
two = 0
three = 0
four = 0
five = 0
six = 0
seven = 0
eight = 0
nine = 0
ten = 0
eleven = 0
twelve = 0
thirteen = 0
fourteen = 0
fifteen = 0
sixteen = 0
seventeen = 0
eighteen = 0
nineteen = 0
twenty = 0
twentyone = 0
twentytwo = 0
twentythree = 0
twentyfour = 0
twentyfive = 0
twentysix = 0
twentyseven = 0
twentyeight = 0
twentynine = 0
thirty = 0
thirtyone = 0
thirtytwo = 0 
thirtythree = 0
thirtyfour = 0
thirtyfive = 0
thirtysix = 0
thirtyseven = 0
thirtyeight = 0
thirtynine = 0
fourty = 0
fourtyone = 0
fourtytwo = 0
fourtythree = 0
fourtyfour = 0
fourtyfive = 0 
fourtysix = 0
fourtyseven = 0
fourtyeight = 0
fourtynine = 0
fifty = 0
fiftyone = 0
fiftytwo = 0
fiftythree = 0
fiftyfour = 0
fiftyfive = 0
fiftysix = 0
fiftyseven = 0
fiftyeight = 0
fiftynine = 0
sixty = 0
sixtyone = 0
sixtytwo = 0
sixtythree = 0
sixtyfour = 0 
sixtyfive = 0
sixtysix = 0
sixtyseven = 0
sixtyeight = 0
sixtynine = 0

row_counter = 0





conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=MACCD')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT first,second,third,fourth,fifth FROM WhiteBalls')

while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        break

    row_counter += 1
    print(row_counter, row)

    if 1 in row:
        one += 1

    if 2 in row:
        two += 1

    if 3 in row:
        three += 1

    if 4 in row:
        four += 1

    if 5 in row:
        five += 1

    if 6 in row:
        six += 1

    if 7 in row:
        seven += 1

    if 8 in row:
        eight += 1

    if 9 in row:
        nine += 1

    if 10 in row:
        ten += 1

    if 11 in row:
        eleven += 1

    if 12 in row:
        twelve += 1

    if 13 in row:
        thirteen += 1

    if 14 in row:
        fourteen += 1

    if 15 in row:
        fifteen += 1

    if 16 in row:
        sixteen += 1

    if 17 in row:
        seventeen += 1

    if 18 in row:
        eighteen += 1

    if 19 in row:
        nineteen += 1

    if 20 in row:
        twenty += 1

    if 21 in row:
        twentyone += 1

    if 22 in row:
        twentytwo += 1

    if 23 in row:
        twentythree += 1

    if 24 in row:
        twentyfour += 1

    if 25 in row:
        twentyfive += 1

    if 26 in row:
        twentysix += 1

    if 27 in row:
        twentyseven += 1

    if 28 in row:
        twentyeight += 1 

    if 29 in row:
        twentynine += 1

    if 30 in row:
        thirty += 1   

    if 31 in row:
        thirtyone += 1

    if 32 in row:
        thirtytwo += 1

    if 33 in row:
        thirtythree += 1

    if 34 in row:
        thirtyfour += 1

    if 35 in row:
        thirtyfive += 1

    if 36 in row:
        thirtysix += 1

    if 37 in row:
        thirtyseven += 1

    if 38 in row:
        thirtyeight += 1

    if 39 in row:
        thirtynine += 1

    if 40 in row:
        fourty += 1

    if 41 in row:
        fourtyone += 1

    if 42 in row:
        fourtytwo += 1

    if 43 in row:
        fourtythree += 1

    if 44 in row:
        fourtyfour += 1

    if 45 in row:
        fourtyfive += 1

    if 46 in row:
        fourtysix += 1

    if 47 in row:
        fourtyseven += 1

    if 48 in row:
        fourtyeight += 1

    if 49 in row:
        fourtynine += 1

    if 50 in row:
        fifty += 1

    if 51 in row:
        fiftyone += 1

    if 52 in row:
        fiftytwo += 1

    if 53 in row:
        fiftythree += 1

    if 54 in row:
        fiftyfour += 1

    if 55 in row:
        fiftyfive += 1

    if 56 in row:
        fiftysix += 1

    if 57 in row:
        fiftyseven += 1

    if 58 in row:
        fiftyeight += 1

    if 59 in row:
        fiftynine += 1

    if 60 in row:
        sixty += 1

    if 61 in row:
        sixtyone += 1

    if 62 in row:
        sixtytwo += 1

    if 63 in row:
        sixtythree += 1

    if 64 in row:
        sixtyfour += 1

    if 65 in row:
        sixtyfive += 1

    if 66 in row:
        sixtysix += 1

    if 67 in row:
        sixtyseven += 1

    if 68 in row:
        sixtyeight += 1

    if 69 in row:
        sixtynine += 1

GreatestNum = max(one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,
eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen,
twenty,twentyone,twentytwo,twentythree,twentyfour,twentyfive,twentysix,
twentyseven,twentyeight,twentynine,
thirty,thirtyone,thirtytwo,thirtythree,thirtyfour,thirtyfive,
thirtysix,thirtyseven,thirtyeight,thirtynine,
fourty,fourtyone,fourtytwo,fourtythree,fourtyfour,fourtyfive,
fourtysix,fourtyseven,fourtyeight,fourtynine,
fifty,fiftyone,fiftytwo,fiftythree,fiftyfour,fiftyfive,
fiftysix,fiftyseven,fiftyeight,fiftynine,
sixty,sixtyone,sixtytwo,sixtythree,sixtyfour,sixtyfive,
sixtysix,sixtyseven,sixtyeight,sixtynine)
LeastNum = min(one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten, 
eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen, 
sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen,twenty,twentyone,twentytwo, 
twentythree,twentyfour,twentyfive,
twentysix,twentyseven,twentyeight,twentynine, 
thirty,thirtyone,thirtytwo,thirtythree,thirtyfour,thirtyfive,
thirtysix,thirtyseven,thirtyeight,thirtynine,
fourty,fourtyone,fourtytwo,fourtythree,fourtyfour,fourtyfive,
fourtysix,fourtyseven,fourtyeight,fourtynine,
fifty,fiftyone,fiftytwo,fiftythree,fiftyfour,fiftyfive,
fiftysix,fiftyseven,fiftyeight,fiftynine,
sixty,sixtyone,sixtytwo,sixtythree,sixtyfour,sixtyfive,
sixtysix,sixtyseven,sixtyeight,sixtynine)

print('rows returned:', row_counter)
print('ones found:', one)
print('twos found:', two)
print('threes found:',three)
print('fours found:',four)
print('fives found:',five)
print('sixs found:',six)
print('sevens found:',seven)
print('eights found:',eight)
print('nines found:',nine)
print('tens found:',ten)
print('elevens found:',eleven)
print('twelves found:',twelve)
print('thirteens found:',thirteen)
print('fourteens found:',fourteen)
print('fifteens found:',fifteen)
print('sixteens found:',sixteen)
print('seventeens found:',seventeen)
print('eighteens found:',eighteen)
print('nineteens found:',nineteen)
print('twentys found:',twenty)
print('twentyones found:',twentyone)
print('twentytwos found:',twentytwo)
print('twentythrees found:',twentythree)
print('twentyfours found:',twentyfour)
print('twentyfives found:',twentyfive)
print('twentysixs found:',twentysix)
print('twentysevens found:',twentyseven)
print('twentyeights found:',twentyeight)
print('twentynines found:',twentynine)
print('thirtys found:',thirty)
print('thirtyones found:',thirtyone)
print('thirtytwos found:',thirtytwo)
print('thirtythrees found:',thirtythree)
print('thirtyfours found:',thirtyfour)
print('thirtyfives found:',thirtyfive)
print('thirtysixs found:',thirtysix)
print('thirtysevens found:',thirtyseven)
print('thirtyeights found:',thirtyeight)
print('thirtynines found:',thirtynine)
print('fourtys found:',fourty)
print('fourtyones found:',fourtyone)
print('fourtytwos found:',fourtytwo)
print('fourtythrees found:',fourtythree)
print('fourtyfours found:',fourtyfour)
print('fourtyfives found:',fourtyfive)
print('fourtysixs found:',fourtysix)
print('fourtysevens found:',fourtyseven)
print('fourtyeights found:',fourtyeight)
print('fourtynines found:',fourtynine)
print('fiftys found:',fifty)
print('fiftyones found:',fiftyone)
print('fiftytwos found:',fiftytwo)
print('fiftythrees found:',fiftythree)
print('fiftyfours found:',fiftyfour)
print('fiftyfives found:',fiftyfive)
print('fiftysixs found:',fiftysix)
print('fiftysevens found:',fiftyseven)
print('fiftyeights found:',fiftyeight)
print('fiftynines found:',fiftynine)
print('sixtys found:',sixty)
print('sixtyones found:',sixtyone)
print('sixtytwos found:',sixtytwo)
print('sixtythrees found:',sixtythree)
print('sixtyfours found:',sixtyfour)
print('sixtyfives found:',sixtyfive)
print('sixtysixs found:',sixtysix)
print('sixtysevens found:',sixtyseven)
print('sixtyeights found:',sixtyeight)
print('sixtynines found:',sixtynine)
print('the number of times that the Greatest number has been played 
is',GreatestNum)
print('the number of times that the Least number has been played 
is',LeastNum)
print('Finished!')
```

Comment: Your question is a litte confusing. What exactly have you tried and where is your error, then?

Comment: You should really learn to use data structures before continuing with this task. Perhaps go through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: It's sort of impressive that you persevered through writing that, but did you not wonder if there were better ways? It seems like you just want a `collections.Counter`, which exposes the `most_common` value for you.

Comment: To get the English name of the number, consider storing a mapping from the number to its name in a dictionary https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: My problem is that when i am using the min and max functions it gives me a an integer not the variable name.  is there another function or some code i can right to make it print the name of the variable and not the integer?

Comment: If you had used a list, dict, or other appropriate data structure, one of the many benefits would be that you would be able to solve your problem without needing to determine variable names.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, what you're doing is very tedious and you should consider going through some more tutorials. Nonetheless, to solve your problem of getting the "name" of the max or min number, you can store a [`list`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) of strings like this:

```
number_names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
# and so on for all numbers
```

Then you can get the name of a number by accessing the value at that index in your list. Like this:

```
print(number_names[0]) # prints 'zero'
print(number_names[5]) # prints 'five'
print(number_names[7]) # prints 'seven'
```

So, in your last few print statements, you can have:

```
print('the number of times that the Greatest number has been played is', number_names[GreatestNum])
print('the number of times that the Least number has been played is', number_names[LeastNum])
```